# What it means to be massive: What benefits and disadvantages do StarCraft 2 units gain by being massive?

Tags: starcraft-2

With the recent patch (1.3.3) Archons are now considered massive units. I was wondering what inherent pros and cons, apart from being immune to concussive shell, are conferred by the 'massive' label.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Massive units can crush the Protoss Sentry's Force Field effect.

Additionally, massive ground units can't be picked up by the Phoenix's gravity beam (thanks, Nick!)

'Massive' is also an armor type (like 'armored' and 'light') and two units (Voidrays and Corruptors) deal bonus damage to massive units.

Comment: Massive units also can't be picked up by the Phoenix's Anti-Gravity beam

Comment: Hmm that is pretty nifty. Is there a list of units that deal bonus damage to massive units? As Corruptors can't damage Archons, what unit poses the biggest threat to them now?

Comment: Void rays are the only other unit with a bonus against massive units. Here's a link to the liquipeida: [click](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Massive)

Comment: @Raven As far as I know the main reason for the change was that they will no longer be slowed by concussive shells. Although the force field crushing adds some interesting possibilities for PvP transitions out of Dark Templar.

Comment: @en1gmatic OP says that explicitly, and I know a lot of Terran have been echoing that sentiment, but I really think breaking Force Field is the impetus behind this change.  Though I have no evidence, if you look at the other (proposed) changes to Protoss, they all revolve around the 4 Gate.  In PvP the 4 Gate has become dominant and adding FF crushing to Archons would force a reassessment of that position.

Comment: @Tzenes - this may be borderline digression, but why? Archons come from templar, which are a gateway unit, no? (Admittedly, they require further tech buildings)

Comment: @Tzenes, and I am really looking forward to trying some forcefield smashing with archons. It has the potential to add a new dynamic to PvP in the mid game. in P v Bio T if I get HT  I would prefer to use storms anyway.

Comment: @Raven one of the reasons 4 Gate tends to be problematic, is that you have to spend all your resources on Stalkers.  This prevents you from countering it with a strong 3 Gate + Robo, as the alternative (Zealot heavy) is countered by Force Fields.  However,  if you could divert your gas into tech-ing to Archons, then you could run Archon/Zealot defense into Archon/Immortal, and smash any 4 Gate -> Colossus build.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Raven's answer, massive units can't be slowed by the Marauder's concussive shell.

Comment: OP already mentioned this...